# How to get the github repo name in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Are there any variables in Azure which I can use to get the name of the source folder(repository name). I tried using **Build.SourcesDirectory** and **System.DefaultWorkingDirectory** , both returned **/Users/runner/work/1/s**. I expect to  get **MyProjectFolderName** which is the source directory of my project in github.

Comment: You're asking for two different things. If you want the repository name, then you don't care what the source folder is. The "source folder" in this case represents **the local path on your agent to which the repo has been cloned**. Did you look at the documentation to see if there are any pre-defined variables that would contain the repository name?

Comment: By source folder, I was referring to the repo name. I though it was obvious that I wasn't referring to the local path on agent where the repo has been cloned - as I get this path using the two variables I mentioned in the question - which I got from the documentation

Comment: My point is that if you want the repo name, why are you looking at the source folder? Did you check the `Build.Repository.Name` variable instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***If you checkout self repo(This is default situation), then just follow Daniel's suggestion is ok:***

`$(Build.Repository.Name)`

yml file like this:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      str = "$(Build.Repository.Name)"
      
      str.split("/")
      
      #get the last name
      print(str.split("/")[-1])
```

[image]

***If you only checkout one repo and not check out self, then just use below yml:***

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: 222
    type: github
    name: xxx/222
    endpoint: xxx
  - repository: 333
    type: github
    name: xxx/333
    endpoint: xxx
variables:
 - name: checkoutreporef
   value: $[ resources.repositories['333'].name ]
steps:
- checkout: 333
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      str = "$(checkoutreporef)"
      
      str.split("/")
      
      #get the last name
      print(str.split("/")[-1])
```

[image]

***If you checkout two and more repo, below yml will help you get the repo names:***

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: 222
    type: github
    name: xxx/xxx
    endpoint: xxx
  - repository: 333
    type: github
    name: xxx/xxx
    endpoint: xxx
steps:
- checkout: 222
- checkout: 333
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      import os
      
      #get current sub folders name
      def getfoldersname():
          folders = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(f)]
          return folders
      #print each folder name
      def printfoldersname():
          for folder in getfoldersname():
              print(folder)
      
      printfoldersname()
```

[image]